# How to paginate a Firebase Recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm starting to use firebase and everything looks great but I have 50k records to show inside a `recyclerview` and I can't figure out how to paginate or something similar because load everything at once takes too much time.
I used `childEventListener` and FirebaseUI as well with no luck.

UPDATE 1:
Finally I got working for the update 1, this is not the best solution for this but I think I'm going to make some changes later.

```
private String lastKey = null;
private List<Comment> commentList = new ArrayList<>();

private final static int QUERY_LIMIT = 20;
private int page = 0;

private void loadComments() {
        page++;
        ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
                commentList.add(comment);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                lastKey = String.valueOf(comment.getTimestamp());

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        if (lastKey != null) {
            commentList.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            comments.child(id_post).orderByChild("timestamp").endAt(lastKey).limitToLast(QUERY_LIMIT * page).addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
        } else {
            comments.child(id_post).orderByChild("timestamp").limitToLast(QUERY_LIMIT).addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have methods to limit results that you can use to implement pagination: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html

Comment: Pagination with Firebase is not easy. It's been [asked and covered dozens of times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+pagination). Unless you show what you've tried and where you are concretely stuck, I vote that this is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a value event listener to limit the number of of results you would like to receive, here is a quick example from firebase-ui

```
ref.limitToLast(5).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot msgSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
        Chat msg = msgSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
        Log.i("Chat", chat.getName()+": "+chat.getText());
    }
}
```

Use the method limitToLast(5) to get the last 5 objects that were added. Other methods with regards to this include limitToFirst(), limitToLast(), startAt(), endAt(), and equalTo()
More information can be found [Here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

I am using this method to show 8 Million Records stored in the Real-time Database, 50 at a time with pagination.

```
private void getUsers(String nodeId) {
    Query query;

    if (nodeId == null)
        query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child(Consts.FIREBASE_DATABASE_LOCATION_USERS)
                .orderByKey()
                .limitToFirst(mPostsPerPage);
    else
        query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child(Consts.FIREBASE_DATABASE_LOCATION_USERS)
                .orderByKey()
                .startAt(nodeId)
                .limitToFirst(mPostsPerPage);

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserModel user;
            List<UserModel> userModels = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                userModels.add(userSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class));
            }

            mAdapter.addAll(userModels);
            mIsLoading = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            mIsLoading = false;
        }
    });
}
```

You also don't have to store the last key separately.

If you are not able to understand it fully then you can [read the blog post here which explains everything](https://blog.shajeelafzal.com/2017/12/13/firebase-realtime-database-pagination-guide-using-recyclerview/).